# ImportError: No module named urls

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-1.7, django-1.11

I have a django rest project which is built on Django1.7. I need to run it on Django 1.11. When i run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

The error is:

```
ImportError: No module named urls
```

on url.py line

```
url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),
```

I have already made modifications in url.py file to avoid patterns. The url.py file look like

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib import admin


admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [

url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),
url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'', include('gcm.urls')),
url(r'^', include('apps.account.urls')),
url(r'^', include('apps.vegetables.urls')),
url(r'^', include('apps.orders.urls')),
url(r'^', include('apps.listings.urls')),
url(r'^', include('apps.rating.urls')),
url(r'^', include('apps.faq.urls')),
url(r'^thank-you/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="thankyou.html"), name="thankyou"),
url(r'^/error/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="error.html"), name="error"),
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="index.html"), name="home"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += [
'',
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
    'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT})]
```

How could i run it?

Comment: Remove grappelli one or put that url at the end

Comment: Is that your full traceback?

Comment: does your settings includes all apps? also check that all apps have urls module within themselves? does this same code worked on previous versions?

Comment: removing grappelli doesnt makes any change.  It works for version1.7

Comment: Is there really a *need* to make it work in version 1.11. Can you just have 1.7 installed in a virtual environment? Otherwise, I'm wondering if you need to do `urlpatterns = patterns('', url( ... ) + static( ...)` instead.

Comment: In Django=1.9+ you, i think you CANT put a string url anymore instead use an import..

Answer (score 0):

In urls.py add this at the bottom,

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT
```

From Django 1.9 it does not support to add the URLs as a string, but it need to be imported as callable. So remove this from your urls.py.

```
urlpatterns += [ '', (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', { 'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT})]
```